# It is possible to set size of images in imagearray of javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, ajax

It is possible to set height and width of images in `imagearray` of javascript?

```
imagearray: [
        ["http://i26.tinypic.com/11l7ls0.jpg", "", "", "My Text"],
        ["http://i29.tinypic.com/xp3hns.jpg", "", "", "My Text"],
        ["http://i30.tinypic.com/531q3n.jpg"],
        ["http://i31.tinypic.com/119w28m.jpg", "", "", "My Text"] 
],
```

Here images are in different height and width.
I wand to set image height and width in constant size (example:400*400)

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand your question—would you be able to edit it to provide more information about what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think trying to solve this in javascript is the correct approach.  You don't actually have any images in your array, you have URLs.  If you hope to manipulate the images with javascript then you're going to have to fetch the images and turn them into data you can actually work with.  This is possible, but it'll be a lot of work as there aren't any built in image processing primitives in javascript.

A better approach may be to get the images into the HTML of your page and then rely on the browser itself to do the work for you.  Insert the image element into your page and specify the width and the height and the browser will scale the image for you:

```
var elImage = document.createElement("img");
elImage.src = "http://i26.tinypic.com/11l7ls0.jpg";
elImage.height = 400;
elImage.width = 400;
elImage.alt = "";
document.getElementById("myImageContainer").appendChild(elImage);
```

The above assumes you've got a div with id myImageContainer to stick the images in.  It could easily be adapted to sit in a loop where you add each image from your array to the page in turn.  However, if this is all you're doing, you might as well just stick the image in to your HTML rather than messing around with javascript:

```
<img src="http://i26.tinypic.com/11l7ls0.jpg" height="400" width="400" alt="" />
```

The main problem with this approach (either scripting or straight to HTML) is that it doesn't preserve aspect ratio, so your images may looked squashed.  If you want to avoid this then you probably do want to use javascript: load the image into your page, detect its 'natural' height and width, then either use simple arithmetic to scale to something that will fit within both the width and height, or scale so that at least one is and display the image inside a div with a fixed width and height and a style of `overflow: hidden` to crop.

Comment: You can avoid the aspect-ratio problem by only specifying the size of one of the dimensions. E.g. if you have a source image of 800w x600h, set the width to 400 and leave out the height attribute, the browser will scale the height to 300. I recently used this technique to have the browser display proportionally-correct thumbnails from variously-sized input images without knowing the input sizes, and without generating separate thumbnail images.

Comment: Good tip, I didn't mention it because it only works with pictures in landscape.  If your source picture is 800wx1200h and you set the width to 400 then the resulting picture will be 600px high, thus exceeding the 400px height requirement.  At this point you're better off doing something more general like I discussed in the last paragraph.  Of course, if you can guarantee all your pictures will be in landscape format, yours is the simpler solution.

Comment: Good point; I ignored that he wants to constrain both width AND height. If you have no height constraint (or vice-versa), the technique works for landscape or portrait images. When I was generating thumbnails I didn't care how deep they'd be, so I set width=40, omitted height, and a 400x800 would go to 40x80, and a 800x400 would go to a 40x20.

I guess if I have to examine whether the source width or height is greater, and scale that to the constraint, then I may as well calc the second value as well instead of omitting it and making the browser figure it out.